# using react navigation with android native activity

Tags: react-native, kotlin, react-navigation

I have a native camera activity written in kotlin, and i want to launch this activity without hiding the bottom tab navigation written in react.

But for now whenever a native activity launches the react navigation disappears.

Is there any way to achieve this?